# netbeans cakephp plugin (local file option)

Tags: cakephp, plugins, netbeans

I am new in cakephp , I want to write the code on an IDE for the code helper thing (ctrl + space) , after downloading and installing the plugin, when I try to add a new project it keeps on telling me

> Please, connect to the network or set CakePHP local file option

Answer (score 0):

It means that the option (Tools > Options > PHP > CakePHP) is not set or you cannot connect to the internet. (Please also see README file at first) 
If you want to use existing source, you have to select Existing Source in New Project Wizard.
Please submit issues to [github issue tracker](https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp-netbeans/issues?sort=created&state=open) if you have them.

Comment: I guess it was just coz of the proxy thing. I have now no proxy and it works fine, thank you.